# How to Iterate every 5th index over numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I want to learn a very basic logic in python . I have two numpy array .
    I want to subtract every 5th index from one array from another.
    So far  I have tried with below code:

```
x=np.arange(25,100).reshape(25,3)
y=x[:,0]
z=x[:,1]
for i in range(0,25,5):        # Till These 2 loop looks fine
   print y[i]
for j in range(0,25,5):
   print z[j]
# Problems portion
for i in range(0,25,5):
    for j in range(0,25,5):
          print y[i]-z[j]
           -1
 -16
 -31
 -46
 -61
  14       #Output
  -1
 -16
 -31
 -46
  29
  14
  -1
 -16
 -31
  44
  29
  14
  -1
 -16
  59
  44
  29
  14
  -1
```

Please suggest where I am making mistake.Why output is above one?
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the simple beauty of numpy.

```
>>> y - z
array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
   -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1])
```

To subtract every fifth position, use slice notation:

```
>>> y[::5] - z[::5]
array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1])
```

Anyway, you're also iterating over all pairs instead of just pairs at the same position. To do it your way, use just one loop:

```
>>> for i in range(0,25,5):
...     print(y[i] - z[i])
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

Comment: just one more doubt ,if both ranges are different ?

Comment: I have given it already.Right now i do not gathered enough reputations. however i have given orange color tick.

Comment: @Poka [Accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) doesn't require reputation.

Comment: I have accepted  the answer. I was not knowing this. Thanks